# Extension to load a specific webpage after idle time

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, redirection, timeout

So I will have a demo computer set up running a specific site for users to interact with. I would like it set up so that somebody can come use it, and then walk away, and the browser will automatically load the homepage again after, say 1 minute of inactivity so it's ready for the next user. This could also be useful if they went to some other site, so the browser could redirect back to the site they are *supposed* to be on.

So, is there a firefox or chrome extension to load a webpage after a certain amount of idle time? (not just refresh)

Thank you,
Blaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what I was looking for. It's a firefox extension called "Reset Kiosk"

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/reset-kiosk/